# Why do Brahmacharis who break the vow of celibacy need to sacrifice a donkey as atonement?

Tags: dharma, caste-system, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, prayaschitta

From Apastamba Dharma Sutras 1.9.26.8:

> A [student] who has broken the vow of chastity, shall offer to Nirṛiti
>   **an ass**, according to the manner of the Pāka-yajña-rites.

This same Prayaschitta is also found in Taittiriya Aranyaka 2:18, Manusmriti 11:119, and Yajñavalkya Smriti 3:280.

How come the Brahmachari has to sacrifice a donkey to atone for this sin?

And also, how does this Prayaschitta even apply in modern times, since Vedic animal sacrifices haven't been done in hundreds of years?

Then, if this prayaschitta can't be done, the Brahmachari loses his caste (and becomes a Shudra), because breaking a vow is cause of loss of caste:

Manusmriti 11.61:

> Defiling a damsel, usury, **breaking a vow**, selling a tank, a
>   garden, one's wife, or child, ...... are all minor offenses **causing
>   loss of caste** (Upapataka).

So does one who breaks the vow of Brahmachari have to do **two** prayaschittas? One for breaking the vow of chastity, and one for regaining the caste on losing it due to breaking the vow of chastity?

Comment: Smritis are almost silent on explaining **why**.

Comment: Brahma Sutras has different atonement. It also depends upon whether one is a Naisthika Brahmachari or not. See verses 5.4.40-43. Here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda 5.4? There are only 4 chapters.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Sorry, my eyes are getting too old. It is 3.4.40-43.